# Jordan measure of connected sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which is connected and not singleton. Is it true that its Jordan measure always non zero?

For $n=1$ the above is true as $A$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 0):

No. Take a line segment $[0, 1] \times \{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2.$